# Anotation "NonNull" in UML?

Tags: java, android-studio, uml

Android Studio is showing the annotation

```
`@NonNull`
```

, how can we represent this in UML?

Similarly, how is there a standard to display annotations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set the multiplicity of your attribute to `[1]` it becomes *not nullable.*

```
- someAttribute : int [1]
```

And since [1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/About-UML/) is the default multiplicity for attributes you can also leave the multiplicity undefined.

```
- someAttribute : int
```

In order to **allow** for null you have to explicitly set the lowerbound to  0

```
- someAttribute : int [0..1]
```

See [UML 2.5 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/About-UML/) chapter 9.5.4 (Property.Notation)

> `<multiplicity-range>` is the multiplicity range of the Property. If this term is omitted, it implies a multiplicity
>   of 1 (exactly one). (See MultiplicityElement – sub clause 7.5.)

Comment: can you please cite the reference so I can search for more information, the answer will also lead my search on other annotations for platforms like Android Studio, Netbeans, thank you.

Comment: I've seen code generators that will not emit an attribute for unspecified multiplicity, and [CanBeNull] on 0..1 and [NotNull] on 1, so depending on your conventions and workflow leaving it undefined may not be equivalent.

Comment: @PeteKirkham well then those code generators are clearly ignoring the UML standard with regards to the default value for the the multiplicity of a property.

Answer (score 1):

A NotNull attribute indicates that the property or association end must be present.

This is equivalent to having a multiplicity of 1 rather than 0..1 or an unspecified multiplicity.